# Open socket server with ssh

Tags: python, python-sockets

I can open a remote socket server to run in background with this terminal command:

```bash
ssh -p22 pi@192.168.100.68 nohup python3 /home/pi/scripts/sock_serv.py &
```

I want to open the server from the client with python like this:

```
import subprocess

def check_ssh():
    cmd = ["ssh", "-p22", "pi@192.168.100.68", "nohup", "python3", "/home/pi/scripts/sock_serv.py", "&"]
    result = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
    print(result)

check_ssh()
```

My problem is the server opens and runs but the above script on the client stays open. I used "nohup" and "&" to have it run in the background but the above script still stays open as long as the socket server is running.

Comment: I guess you actually want to have a systemd service. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/672609